# How to mock classes of external framework with delegates in iOS?

Tags: ios, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, mocking

I am working in an iOS application called `ConnectApp` and I am using a framework called `Connector`. Now, `Connector` framework completes actual connection task with BLE devices and let my caller app (i.e. `ConnectApp`) know the connection request results through `ConnectionDelegate`. Let's see example code,

#### ConnectApp - host app

```
class ConnectionService: ConnectionDelegate {

    func connect(){
        var connector = Connector()
        connector.setDelegate(self)
        connector.connect()
    }

    func onConnected(result: ConnectionResult) {
        //connection result
    }
}
```

#### Connector Framework

```
public class ConnectionResult {
    // many complicated custom variables
}

public protocol ConnectionDelegate {
      func onConnected(result: ConnectionResult)
}

public class Connector {

   var delegate: ConnectionDelegate?

   func setDelegate(delegate: ConnectionDelegate) {
       self.delegate = delegate
   }

   func connect() {
        //…..
        // result = prepared from framework
        delegate?.onConnected(result)
   }
}
```

#### Problem

Sometimes developers have no BLE device and we need to mock the Connector layer of framework. In case of simple classes (i.e. with simpler methods) we could have used inheritance and mock the `Connector` with a `MockConnector` which might override the lower tasks and return status from `MockConnector` class. But when I need to deal with a `ConnectionDelegate` which returns complicated object. How can I resolve this issue?

Note that framework does not provide interfaces of the classes rather we need to find way around for concrete objects like, `Connector`, `ConnectionDelegate` etc.

#### Update 1:

Trying to apply Skwiggs's answer so I created protocol like,

```
protocol ConnectorProtocol: Connector {
    associatedType MockResult: ConnectionResult
}
```

And then injecting real/mock using strategy pattern like,

```
class ConnectionService: ConnectionDelegate {

    var connector: ConnectorProtocol? // Getting compiler error
    init(conn: ConnectorProtocol){
        connector = conn
    }

    func connect(){
        connector.setDelegate(self)
        connector.connect()
    }

    func onConnected(result: ConnectionResult) {
        //connection result
    }
}
```

Now I am getting compiler error,

> Protocol 'ConnectorProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Your `ConnectionService` class has to be specific to which actual connector you want to mock (and then declare a type that conforms to `ConnectorProtocol`, and use that type for your `var connector: YourMockConnector`). I'm not familiar with the Connector framework, but you'll probably need a mock connection class per BLE device you want to connect to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, the cleanest way to create a Seam (a separation that allows us to substitute different implementations) is to define a protocol. This requires changing the production code to talk to the protocol, instead of a hard-coded dependency like `Connector()`.

First, create the protocol. Swift lets us attach new protocols to existing types.

```
protocol ConnectorProtocol {}

extension Connector: ConnectorProtocol {}
```

This defines a protocol, initially empty. And it says that `Connector` conforms to this protocol.

What belongs in the protocol? You can discover this by changing the type of `var connector` from the implicit `Connector` to an explicit `ConnectorProtocol`:

```
var connector: ConnectorProtocol = Connector()
```

Xcode will complain about unknown methods. Satisfy it by copying the signature of each method it needs into the protocol. Judging from your code sample, it may be:

```
protocol ConnectorProtocol {
    func setDelegate(delegate: ConnectionDelegate)
    func connect()
}
```

Because `Connector` already implements these methods, the protocol extension is satisfied.

Next, we need a way for the production code to use `Connector`, but for test code to substitute a different implementation of the protocol. Since `ConnectionService` creates a new instance when `connect()` is called, we can use a closure as a simple Factory Method. The production code can supply a default closure (creating a `Connector`) like with a closure property:

```
private let makeConnector: () -> ConnectorProtocol
```

Set its value by passing an argument to the initializer. The initializer can specify a default value, so that it makes a real `Connector` unless told otherwise:

```
init(makeConnector: (() -> ConnectorProtocol) = { Connector() }) {
    self.makeConnector = makeConnector
    super.init()
}
```

In `connect()`, call `makeConnector()` instead of `Connector()`. Since we don't have unit tests for this change, do a manual test to confirm we didn't break anything.

Now our Seam is in place, so we can begin writing tests. There are two types of tests to write:

1. Are we calling `Connector` correctly?
2. What happens when the delegate method is called?

Let's make a Mock Object to check the first part. It's important that we call `setDelegate(delegate:)` before calling `connect()`, so let's have the mock record all calls in an array. The array gives us a way to check the call order. Instead of having the test code examine the array of calls (acting as a Test Spy which just records stuff), your test will be cleaner if we make this a full-fledged Mock Object — meaning it will do its own verification.

```
final class MockConnector: ConnectorProtocol {
    private enum Methods {
        case setDelegate(ConnectionDelegate)
        case connect
    }

    private var calls: [Methods] = []

    func setDelegate(delegate: ConnectionDelegate) {
        calls.append(.setDelegate(delegate))
    }

    func connect() {
        calls.append(.connect)
    }

    func verifySetDelegateThenConnect(
        expectedDelegate: ConnectionDelegate,
        file: StaticString = #file,
        line: UInt = #line
    ) {
        if calls.count != 2 {
            fail(file: file, line: line)
            return
        }
        guard case let .setDelegate(delegate) = calls[0] else {
            fail(file: file, line: line)
            return
        }
        guard case .connect = calls[1] else {
            fail(file: file, line: line)
            return
        }
        if expectedDelegate !== delegate {
            XCTFail(
                "Expected setDelegate(delegate:) with \(expectedDelegate), but was \(delegate)",
                file: file,
                line: line
            )
        }
    }

    private func fail(file: StaticString, line: UInt) {
        XCTFail("Expected setDelegate(delegate:) followed by connect(), but was \(calls)", file: file, line: line)
    }
}
```

(That business with passing around `file` and `line`? This makes it so that any test failure will report the line that calls `verifySetDelegateThenConnect(expectedDelegate:)`, instead of the line that calls `XCTFail(_)`.)

Here's how you'd use this in `ConnectionServiceTests`:

```
func test_connect_shouldMakeConnectorSettingSelfAsDelegateThenConnecting() {
    let mockConnector = MockConnector()
    let service = ConnectionService(makeConnector: { mockConnector })

    service.connect()

    mockConnector.verifySetDelegateThenConnect(expectedDelegate: service)
}
```

That takes care of the first type of test. For the second type, there's no need to test that `Connector` calls the delegate. You know it does, and it's outside your control. Instead, write a test to call the delegate method directly. (You'll still want it to make a `MockConnector` to prevent any calls to the real `Connector`).

```
func test_onConnected_withCertainResult_shouldDoSomething() {
    let service = ConnectionService(makeConnector: { MockConnector() })
    let result = ConnectionResult(…) // Whatever you need

    service.onConnected(result: result)

    // Whatever you want to verify
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
protocol MockConnector: Connector {
    associatedType MockResult: ConnectionResult
}
```

Then, for each connector you need to mock, define a concrete class that conforms to this mock connector

```
class SomeMockConnector: MockConnector {
    struct MockResult: ConnectionResult {
        // Any mocked variables for this connection result here 
    }

    // implement any further requirements from the Connector class
    var delegate: ConnectionDelegate?

    func connect() {
        // initialise your mock result with any specific data
        let mockResult = MockResult()
        delegate?.onConnected(mockResult)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got `compiler error` when I try to apply your proposed solution. Please see my updated post. It would be helpful if you add host apps example code after applying your solution?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan The problem is that I have no idea what this Connector framework does and for what, so it's hard for me to give you an example...

Comment: Lets say connector class does a single work i.e. connect.

Comment: You just described the responsibility of your MockProtocol :p Like, what does `connect()` entail ? what sort of data does this function expect / return ? What BLE device are you trying to mock a connection to, and what is required for a successful connection? If you can update your question with some additional details I can update this answer with more precision & possible examples.